# Updating DataGrid Info in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a Silverlight 4 application that uses a DataGrid. This DataGrid is bound to a List of approximately 1,000 records. One of the columns on this grid is dynamic in the sense that it should update once every thirty seconds.

I have a DispatcherTimer setup that is triggered every 30 seconds. My question is, what is the best way for me to update the values of just that one column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make each dataitem representing the row implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, and raise the event when you update the column value. This should work by displayng the canges as soon as you update the variable.

Comment: My problem is, The property (a DateTime) doesn't change values. I have a value converter on the column that calculates the time since the record was created. Because the property itself doesn't change values, the value converter never gets triggered. Is there a way to manually trigger this?

Comment: Use some sort of timer and trigger manually the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: But how do I manually trigger the INotifyPropertyChanged event on a collection of objects? Do I need to look through the collection and fire the event one at a time? Or is there a more elegant way?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I suppose that looping was the best solution, may be you can optimize by looping just the visible portion of the grid.